# Reset vimrc not to use `$` symbol as eol convention

Tags: vim

I added a `.vimrc` file to make my vim more useful for me.

As I am a new user,  I just downloaded it online. But since then each EOL is marked by a `$` symbol,  and I find that a bit irritating.

Can you help me resetting it?

here is an example on my terminal vim editor:

```
  1 here is dollor symbol to each EOL$
  2 i don't want this$
  3 this is very irritating for me$
  4 any help$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lookup for `listchars` in your vimrc (and/or your plugins)

if you want to reset it manually:

```
:set listchars=
```

to show some help about it:

[`:he listchars`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27listchars%27)

Comment: Thanks @zmo though there was list only, but it helped. htanks alot..:)

Comment: @zmo I think you are confused. There is an ex command `:list` which is not short for anything. There are also 2 options `'list'` and `'listchars'`, which I assume you are referring to. `'list'` is a boolean to turn off/on invisible characters. `'listchars'` is a string that tells how to display invisible characters. You probably want to do `:set nolist` to turn off the `'list'` option instead of trashing the `'listchars'` value. For more information see `:h 'list'` and `:h 'listchars'`.

Comment: my bad, I should drink more (or less?) coffee before answering to comments ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you see those trailing `$` characters, that means that you have

```
:set list
```

It's not recommended to keep this turned on all the time, for it has some side effects (e.g. with soft word wrapping), and also changes other characters (e.g. each `<Tab>` into `^I`).

To modify the appearance, you can modify the `'listchars'` option to suit your preferences. See `:help 'listchars'` for details. All of those changes need to be put into your `~/.vimrc` to persist.